# How to put bibitem-labels as side margin notes?

Tags: bibtex, marginnote

Inspired by the beautiful [template](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-manuel-kuehner/) of Manuel Kühner, I am using the package `marginnote` in combination with `scrbook` to be able to annotate in my main text, which works fine.

[image: Example of two pages with text and annotations]

Unfortunately this has an (in my opinion) ugly side effect in my bibliography, where I do not use the extra space for side notes.

[image: Example of two pages of the bibliography]

I would love to have the identifiers of the bibitems within the sidemargin and use the extra space (taken by the identifiers right now, area in red in the picture) for the references, too.

[image: Example of the two pages that I would love to get]

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start. My plan B is to write an parsing script for the .bbl-file, but I think there has to be an solution based on LaTeX only.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Here is the MWE to produce the pdf I took the pictures from.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed for blindtext
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\myMarginnote}[1]{%
    \marginnote{% needs marginnote package
        \ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}% needs ragged2e package
        \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen% 
        \normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize%
        #1}
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{inner=20mm, outer=40mm, bottom=30mm, top=30mm,    marginparsep=3mm,   marginparwidth=30mm}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

% Define width of header
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

% Define with of header line
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}

\ohead{\headmark}
\lefoot{\llap{\pagemark~}}
\rofoot{    \rlap{~\pagemark}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\markboth{left header}{right header}
\nocite{*}
~\newpage
\blindtext\myMarginnote{foobar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{bar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{foobar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{bar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{foobar foo foo foobar bar bar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{bar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{foobar}
\blindtext\myMarginnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext[4]

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

And here the content of `literatur.bib` (the [20 most cited papers](http://www.nature.com/news/the-top-100-papers-1.16224), taken by google-scholar):

```
@article{lowry1951protein,
  title={Protein measurement with the {Folin} phenol reagent},
  author={Lowry, Oliver H and Rosebrough, Nira J and Farr, A Lewis and Randall, Rose J and others},
  journal={J biol Chem},
  volume={193},
  number={1},
  pages={265--275},
  year={1951}
}

@article{laemmli1970cleavage,
  title={Cleavage of structural proteins during the assembly of the head of bacteriophage {T4}},
  author={Laemmli, Ulrich K and others},
  journal={nature},
  volume={227},
  number={5259},
  pages={680--685},
  year={1970},
  publisher={London}
}

@article{bradford1976rapid,
  title={A rapid and sensitive method for the quantitation of microgram quantities of protein utilizing the principle of protein-dye binding},
  author={Bradford, Marion M},
  journal={Analytical biochemistry},
  volume={72},
  number={1},
  pages={248--254},
  year={1976},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{sanger1977dna,
  title={{DNA} sequencing with chain-terminating inhibitors},
  author={Sanger, Frederick and Nicklen, Steven and Coulson, Alan R},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={74},
  number={12},
  pages={5463--5467},
  year={1977},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}

@article{chomczynski1987single,
  title={Single-step method of {RNA} isolation by acid guanidinium thiocyanate-phenol-chloroform extraction},
  author={Chomczynski, Piotr and Sacchi, Nicoletta},
  journal={Analytical biochemistry},
  volume={162},
  number={1},
  pages={156--159},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{towbin1979electrophoretic,
  title={Electrophoretic transfer of proteins from polyacrylamide gels to nitrocellulose sheets: procedure and some applications},
  author={Towbin, Harry and Staehelin, Theophil and Gordon, Julian},
  journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  volume={76},
  number={9},
  pages={4350--4354},
  year={1979},
  publisher={National Acad Sciences}
}

@article{lee1988development,
  title={Development of the Colle-Salvetti correlation-energy formula into a functional of the electron density},
  author={Lee, Chengteh and Yang, Weitao and Parr, Robert G},
  journal={Physical review B},
  volume={37},
  number={2},
  pages={785},
  year={1988},
  publisher={APS}
}

@article{becke1993density,
  title={Density-functional thermochemistry. III. The role of exact exchange},
  author={Becke, Axel D},
  journal={The Journal of chemical physics},
  volume={98},
  number={7},
  pages={5648--5652},
  year={1993},
  publisher={AIP Publishing}
}

@article{folch1957simple,
  title={A simple method for the isolation and purification of total lipids from animal tissues},
  author={Folch, Jordi and Lees, M\_ and Sloane-Stanley, GH and others},
  journal={J biol chem},
  volume={226},
  number={1},
  pages={497--509},
  year={1957}
}

@article{thompson1994clustal,
  title={{CLUSTAL W}: improving the sensitivity of progressive multiple sequence alignment through sequence weighting, position-specific gap penalties and weight matrix choice},
  author={Thompson, Julie D and Higgins, Desmond G and Gibson, Toby J},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  volume={22},
  number={22},
  pages={4673--4680},
  year={1994},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{kaplan1958nonparametric,
  title={Nonparametric estimation from incomplete observations},
  author={Kaplan, Edward L and Meier, Paul},
  journal={Journal of the American statistical association},
  volume={53},
  number={282},
  pages={457--481},
  year={1958},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{altschul1990basic,
  title={Basic local alignment search tool},
  author={Altschul, Stephen F and Gish, Warren and Miller, Webb and Myers, Eugene W and Lipman, David J},
  journal={Journal of molecular biology},
  volume={215},
  number={3},
  pages={403--410},
  year={1990},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{sheldrick2007short,
  title={A short history of {SHELX}},
  author={Sheldrick, George M},
  journal={Acta Crystallographica Section A: Foundations of Crystallography},
  volume={64},
  number={1},
  pages={112--122},
  year={2007},
  publisher={International Union of Crystallography}
}

@article{altschul1997gapped,
  title={Gapped BLAST and PSI-BLAST: a new generation of protein database search programs},
  author={Altschul, Stephen F and Madden, Thomas L and Sch{\"a}ffer, Alejandro A and Zhang, Jinghui and Zhang, Zheng and Miller, Webb and Lipman, David J},
  journal={Nucleic acids research},
  volume={25},
  number={17},
  pages={3389--3402},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Oxford Univ Press}
}

@article{murashige1962revised,
  title={A revised medium for rapid growth and bio assays with tobacco tissue cultures},
  author={Murashige, Toshio and Skoog, Folke},
  journal={Physiologia plantarum},
  volume={15},
  number={3},
  pages={473--497},
  year={1962},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@article{perdew1996generalized,
  title={Generalized gradient approximation made simple},
  author={Perdew, John P and Burke, Kieron and Ernzerhof, Matthias},
  journal={Physical review letters},
  volume={77},
  number={18},
  pages={3865},
  year={1996},
  publisher={APS}
}

@article{folstein1975mini,
  title={“Mini-mental state”: a practical method for grading the cognitive state of patients for the clinician},
  author={Folstein, Marshal F and Folstein, Susan E and McHugh, Paul R},
  journal={Journal of psychiatric research},
  volume={12},
  number={3},
  pages={189--198},
  year={1975},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{bligh1959rapid,
  title={A rapid method of total lipid extraction and purification},
  author={Bligh, E Graham and Dyer, W Justin},
  journal={Canadian journal of biochemistry and physiology},
  volume={37},
  number={8},
  pages={911--917},
  year={1959},
  publisher={NRC Research Press}
}

@article{southern1975detection,
  title={Detection of specific sequences among DNA fragments separated by gel electrophoresis},
  author={Southern, Edwin Mellor},
  journal={Journal of molecular biology},
  volume={98},
  number={3},
  pages={503--517},
  year={1975},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{saitou1987neighbor,
  title={The neighbor-joining method: a new method for reconstructing phylogenetic trees.},
  author={Saitou, Naruya and Nei, Masatoshi},
  journal={Molecular biology and evolution},
  volume={4},
  number={4},
  pages={406--425},
  year={1987},
  publisher={SMBE}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it is not a good idea to put bib labels in the right margin: You are forcing the reader to go to the right margin find the label and then back the whole line. But if you want ...

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed for blindtext
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\myMarginnote}[1]{%
    \marginnote{% needs marginnote package
        \ifthispageodd{\RaggedRight}{\RaggedLeft}% needs ragged2e package
        \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen%
        \normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize%
        #1}%
}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{inner=20mm, outer=40mm, bottom=30mm, top=30mm,    marginparsep=3mm,   marginparwidth=30mm}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

% Define width of header
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

% Define with of header line
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}

\ohead{\headmark}
\lefoot{\llap{\pagemark~}}
\rofoot{    \rlap{~\pagemark}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\markboth{left header}{right header}
\nocite{*}

\makeatletter
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[\hfill]\leavevmode\myMarginnote{\@biblabel{#1}}\if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\renewcommand\@openbib@code{% change the list parameters
    \setlength\labelwidth{0pt}%
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \setlength\labelsep{0pt}%
    }

\renewcommand{\myMarginnote}[1]{%
    \marginnote{% needs marginnote package
        \ifthispageodd{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}%to avoid underfull messages
        \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen%
        \normalfont\sffamily\scriptsize%
        #1}%
}    
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{literatur}
\end{document}
```

[image]